# How to properly test a React component that renders a child conditionally based on state, event listeners and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I have this component `DescriptionText.tsx`:

```js
export const DescriptionText = ({ text }: DescriptionTextProps) => {
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);

  const [isClamped, setClamped] = useState(false);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const clampChecker = () => {
    if (contentRef && contentRef.current) {
      const isClamped = contentRef.current.scrollHeight > contentRef.current.clientHeight;
      setClamped(isClamped);
      return isClamped;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const toggleExpanded = () => {
    setExpanded((prev) => !prev);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = clampChecker;
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    // Call clampChecker on initial mount
    clampChecker();

    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  //? Prevent default behavior of Link that causes page to refresh
  const handleExpandClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleExpanded();
  };

  const truncatedText = <TruncatedText ref={contentRef}>{text}</TruncatedText>;
  return (
    <Text data-testid="description-ref">
      {expanded ? text : truncatedText}
      {isClamped && (
        <Link href="#" onClick={handleExpandClick} data-testid="link">
          {expanded ? ' see less' : ' see more'}
        </Link>
      )}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

I am rendering the `<DescriptionText>` component in a unit test using the `render` method from react testing library.

- I have tried accessing the `<Link>` element using all screen methods (testId, role, text) both synchronously and asynchronously using `waitFor` in my test.
- None of those methods worked and the test simply cannot find the `<Link>` element.
- I also tried using `act()` and `renderHook()` but am not sure if I was able to implement those correctly.
- I am not keen on using JSDOM.

After all that work, I can only intuit that somehow the `<Link>` component is not mounting in the jest virtual DOM, or somehow the window event listeners are not working as expected in the same. Also eslint discourages use of `screen.debug()`.

So, in conclusion, how can I access the Link element using its testId in a unit test?